# Expected value of gain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The operator of a tour has a bus with 20 seats. The operator knows for experience that it can occur that not all of the tourist make it on time, so he sells 21 tickets. The probability that a tourist doesn't make it on time for the tour is 0.02, which is independent from other tourists. Every ticket costs 50 and there is no refunding in case a tourist doesn't arrive. If a tourist arrives and there's no seats available the operator of the tour has to pay 100 for the cost of the ticket and 50 more to the tourist. What is the expected value of gain for the operator of the tour?

I know it is a binomial distribution (with n trials and success meaning that the tourist showed up on time, p= 0.98), but if we let W= gain, I can only see to possible values 21*50  and 21*50 - 3*50 = 18*50, which would make W have a Bernoulli distribution (with success meaning he won 21*50). But I don't really know how to state this formally. Also $P(W=21*50)= P(X \leq 20)$, and $P(W=18*50)=1- P(X \leq 20)= P(X=21)$.

Comment: It looks like your last sentence does say it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there are only two possible results.  He gets $900$ if all $21$ show up and $1050$ otherwise.  So his expected gain is $900 \cdot P(21) + 1050 \cdot (1-P(21))$.  If less than $21$ show up, you don't care how many it is, so you don't need to calculate the chance of $19, 18, \dots$ (though you could).